# Verifiable Credentials Wallet

Tags: programming-practices, development-process

I'm working on a project that requires the use of verifiable credentials, and I'm looking to build a wallet that can store and manage these credentials according to the W3C standard. However, I'm trying to avoid using a blockchain for this purpose. Are there any alternative technologies or approaches that I could use to implement a W3C-compliant verifiable credentials wallet? I'm open to any suggestions or recommendations that you might have.

Comment: We need to know the reason you’re avoiding using a block chain. Alternatives might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Hashgraph

---

**Hashgraph:** is a good alternative technology to blockchains. it is fast, secure, and efficient DLT. And [Hedera](https://docs.hedera.com/guides/) can help you with it, they offer Crypto, token, consensus, file, and smart contract services using the **hashgraph** consensus algorithm with decent documentation. And they have **+100 open source Repositories** on their [Github](https://github.com/hashgraph).